# UITableViewCell wrong width on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

My tableview size is 500 by 500. I am creating a UITableViewCell and setting it's style as default in init method. However, when I log the frame of the cell, it comes out as 320. Is this normal? Thanks

Also, for some reason, I can't use the reuse identifier if I init the cell with a frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly possible that `UITableViewCell`'s initializer just hardcodes the width to 320 points. After all, at this point the cell does not yet belong to a table view so it can't possibly know its final size.